# Song of Jamaica. probably overwatered, need suggestions how to save the plant

Tags: watering, sunlight, dracaena

Because of the war here in Ukraine, the plant was kept in a basement without any sunlight for a month before we took it to our house.
Today we discovered, that there are no drainage holes, so there is a probably an overwatering issue too.

We need some suggestions on how to help the plant survive. As you can see on the photos, some of the stems already look withered, we also cut a branch and it had rot inside

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes it is overwatered which is a typical problem in the low light interior settings. Here are my recommendations:

- cut back dead growth until you see live material.  Chances are good that whole stems will die back so you might have to remove it to the ground
- move to the highest light level you have: next to a south facing window
- reduce watering: even to once a month
- remove the stones on the surface of the soil as they keep the soil moister than it needs to be
- make sure the pot allows water to drain from the bottom.  Pots without drainage are not suitable for these plants
- do not fertilize: wait till next year when you see new growth
- be patient: most plants can outgrow this problem if the causes are corrected but it takes time

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips